# Message misrendering line-wrapped Boxes in strings

Tags: warning-messages, boxes, rendering

Consider this simple incorporation of [`Boxes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boxes.html) which render [`MatrixForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixForm.html) into a [`Message`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Message.html):

```
str = ToString @ StandardForm @ MatrixForm @ {{.1, .2}, {.3, .4}};

f::error = "`1`";
Message[f::error, "blah blah blah blah blah blah " <> str]
```

Evaluated in a sufficiently wide notebook, this renders correctly as

[image]

This works because `str` is a [string encoding of `Boxes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TextualInputAndOutput.html#28564) and can be concatenated with plaintext strings:

```
str // FullForm
```

```
"\!\(\*TagBox[RowBox[{\"(\", \"\[NoBreak]\", GridBox[{{\"0.1`\", \"0.2`\"}, {\"0.3`\", \"0.4`\"}}, Rule[RowSpacings, 1], Rule[ColumnSpacings, 1], Rule[RowAlignments, Baseline], Rule[ColumnAlignments, Center]], \"\[NoBreak]\", \")\"}], Function[BoxForm`e$, MatrixForm[BoxForm`e$]]]\)"
```

However, if we resize our notebook window such that the `Message` output gets line-wrapped...

[image]

and re-evaluate `Message`, it now mysteriously fails to render!

[image]

If we remove the invocation of `MatrixForm`...

```
str = ToString @ StandardForm @ {{.1, .2}, {.3, .4}};
Message[f::error, "blah blah blah blah blah blah " <> str]
```

then the output misrenders in a different way, exposing the `Boxes` string:

[image]

Furthermore, when the correctly-rendered graphic is relatively large, it fails to render at notebook widths that are still much wider than those necessary to cause post-rendering line-wrap!

[image]

[image]

This is quite a debilitating bug in my use-case, since it precludes insightful maths-formatted error messages for a library I develop. It seems it is specific to `Message`: I have not replicated it in other methods (like `Echo`) which happily render with line-wrapping. Is there a workaround?